# Enzyme shallow styled component output snapshot that does not have className

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, styled-components, enzyme-to-snapshot

I have a simple test with enzyme to shallow a styled.div`` with some css in it. But the snapshot does not className in it

This is the snapshot:

```
exports[`<Example /> should render correctly 1`] = `
<styled.div
  onClick={[Function]}
>
  This is 
  left
</styled.div>
`;
```

What i expected is `<div className>` but i had styled.div